# Generate data in NiFi within a specific range

Tags: apache-nifi

I am creating test data using NiFi and publishing it to Kafka. The data format is JSON (which I specified in the custom text of Generate Flow File):

```
{
"id":1,
"name": "John",
"inst_code":"HBA"
}
```

Requirement is to have data of a specific range, i.e. the `id` should be from `0` to `1,000,000` and `inst_code` should be either `O` or `K`.

I achieved this partially by using the following flow (except the upper range limit part):
GenerateFlowFile-> UpdateAttribute -> LookupAttribute -> ReplaceText

Where the UpdateAttribute has the below setting using the **Store State Locally** option:

```
Stateful Variables Initial Value->0
lookupnum -> ${random():mod(2):plus(1)}
seq-> ${getStateValue("seq"):plus(1)}
```

I used a SimpleKeyValueLookupService to lookup a random value of `O` and `K` based on the value of `lookupnum`. Later used ReplaceText to replace the value of `id` (using value of seq) and  `inst_code` using the value from the lookup service.

This is working, but the only thing I am not able to think of is to set an upper limit of `1,000,000` to the `seq` attribute which I am using for the `id` field. How can it be achieved?

PS: I am unable to add screenshots as it is blocked

Comment: Check the nextInt expression language function. Or you can use script to generate or modify json.

Comment: @daggett . Is there a way to stop the GenerateFlowFile after a specific number of flowfiles were generated?